# Copy all attachments of a message to an embed

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make it so that my bot can completely copy a message, including all of its attachments, if any.

How can I get these attachments from my `Message` class and add them to my embed?

```
       attachment = message.attachments.first()
       if (message.attachments.size > 0) embed.setImage(attachment.url)
```

This is what I have right now but only the first attachment shows up if there's more than one. How can I make it so that all of the attachments are added to the embed?

Answer (score 1):

You're only getting the first attachment because you're only fetching the first attachment, the `<message>.attachments.first()` function gets the first attachment from the message.

`<message>.attachments` returns a collection of all the attachments in the message so the easiest way imo is to put it in an array and run a `forEach()` function

```
let attachments = Array.from(message.attachments.values());
attachments.forEach(attachment => console.log(attachment.url))
```